# Reset Entire Activity in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

I need help to reset an entire activity after i am done with it, so that when I comeback to it, everything is back to it's original setting.

So, I have an activity named `ColorGame` and `Scoreboard`. What I want to happen is to after I finish playing in `ColorGame` Activity, it will go to `Scoreboard` (which is working fine). Then in `Scoreboard` Activity, I have a button that either will go to the main menu or to go back and play again in `ColorGame` Activity. I have an intent from `Scoreboard` to the `ColorGame` activity, however, everytime I click the `PLAYAGAIN` button to return to play the game again, the points and time is still the same number from the previous game. Could you guys help me?

I have these codes. This is my code for `ColorGame` to `ScoreBoard`:

```
Intent goScoreBoard = new Intent(ColorGame.this, ScoreBoard.class);
goScoreBoard.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
finish();
startActivity(goScoreBoard);
```

and this is my codes for `ScoreBoard` to `ColorGame`:

```
Intent playAgain = new Intent(ScoreBoard.this, ColorGame.class);
playAgain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
finish();
startActivity(playAgain);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using single top launch mode for the Activity. You should implement `onNewIntent` in ColorGame and reset all the data in the Activity there.